# Sessions Helper Method Not Defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a sessionsController and I'm trying to add a redirect_back_or method in my sessions_helper to allow friendly forwarding.

Here is the error I get:

```
undefined method `redirect_back_or' for #<SessionsController:0x007f9fa1b51ec0>
```

I have restarted the server and can't figure out why it's not finding this method in my helper.

My Sessions helper code is as follows:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def deny_access
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "Please sign in to access this page."
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
      redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
      clear_return_to
  end

  private

  def store_location
        session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
  end

  def clear_return_to
    session[:return_to] = nil
  end

end
```

My sessions controller is

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_back_or user
    #redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed out!"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that method in `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private
  def redirect_back_or(default)
      redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
      clear_return_to
  end
end
```

**Or** include the `SessionsHelper` module in your controller to use the method:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include SessionsHelper
  ...
```

Comment: You create or designate a helper method when you want to use it on a view file.  It's true that you could put this method on the `ApplicationController`, but if you did that you wouldn't need to declare it as a `helper_method` in order to access it from the controller.  You should never be redirecting from a view file, so there would be no need to declare it as a helper method.

Comment: Yes you are right, one should not be redirecting from views. I'll edit. I extracted from helper module and got confused.

Comment: This also explains why putting the methods inside of the `SessionsHelper` class doesn't make any sense...  Read here for more information on when to use helper methods: http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/49-using-helper-methods-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Agreed, but I'll leave it as such, one may put methods in a module to be included in several places, although here it's a helper module and indeed makes little sense to do that. Other than that, you have to agree that both suggestions do solve the OP issue.

Comment: hmmm, ok - interesting. I'm following along with http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ and he recommends using helpers for this. I'll try moving it to the controller.

Comment: @clyfe's suggestion of putting in the `ApplicationController` is a smart one if you're planning on using these methods repeatedly across controllers, as any method in your `ApplicationController` can be accessed from any other controller.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to call a method that's on your SessionsHelper file from your Controller.  The helper file is for adding methods to be used in the view.  You should move the `redirect_back_or` method to the `SessionsController`.  Or if you want to be able to use this method repeatedly in multiple controllers, it might be preferable to put it in your `ApplicationController`.  I would recommend you do the same with your `deny_access` method.  It would make more sense to do that anyways since you wouldn't be redirecting from a view file anyways.